# Porting simplest AES ECB to C#

Tags: python, c#, aes, porting

I try to port a quite simple python snippet to C#. My code is actually working, but does not produces the same output for a given input.

The "reference implementation" I got in Python:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import binascii


def enc_aes(k, v):
    mode = AES.MODE_ECB
    enc  = AES.new(k, mode)
    result = enc.encrypt(v)
    return result


actual = enc_aes(b'000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f', b'0102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f00')
expected = b'7f0ee20c29fb1a5603674bc93f3bd850da4a2eb3bf1ab9117b70b7812e55160d'

print("  actual:", binascii.hexlify(actual))
print("expected:", expected)
print("Passed" if binascii.hexlify(actual) == expected else "FAILED")
```

My code so far in order to achieve the same result:

```
    [TestClass]
    public class AESTest
    {
        private static readonly int _hlen = 128;
        private static readonly byte[] _IV = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestEnc()
        {
            // 0x000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f 128 Bits
            byte[] k = {0x0f, 0x0e, 0x0d, 0x0c, 0x0b, 0x0a, 0x09, 0x08, 0x07, 0x06, 0x05, 0x04, 0x03, 0x02, 0x01, 0x00};
            // 0x0102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f00 128 Bits
            byte[] v = {0x00, 0x0f, 0x0e, 0x0d, 0x0c, 0x0b, 0x0a, 0x09, 0x08, 0x07, 0x06, 0x05, 0x04, 0x03, 0x02, 0x01};
            // 0x7f0ee20c29fb1a5603674bc93f3bd850da4a2eb3bf1ab9117b70b7812e55160d 256 Bits
            byte[] expected = {0x0d, 0x16, 0x55, 0x2e, 0x81, 0xb7, 0x70, 0x7b, 0x11, 0xb9, 0x1a, 0xbf, 0xb3, 0x2e, 0x4a, 0xda, 0x50, 0xd8, 0x3b, 0x3f, 0xc9, 0x4b, 0x67, 0x03, 0x56, 0x1a, 0xfb, 0x29, 0x0c, 0xe2, 0x0e, 0x7f};

            byte[] actual = enc_aes(k, v);

            Assert.IsTrue(expected.SequenceEqual(actual));
        }

        public static byte[] enc_aes(byte[] k, byte[] v)
        {
            Aes aes = Aes.Create();
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            //aes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
            //aes.Key = k;
            //...

            ICryptoTransform enc = aes.CreateEncryptor(k, _IV);
            byte[] result = enc.TransformFinalBlock(v, 0, v.Length);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please share your most recent C# code.

Comment: We can't debug code you don't give us, and I'm not installing Python to test the code you did post.

Comment: @Topaco: I deliberately did not give any code because I probably took a completely wrong approach. But well, just a moment ...

Comment: @Cory: Why so rude?

Comment: Change the following in the C# code to be consistent with the Python code: UTF8 encode the key and plaintext. Don't pass an IV (ECB doesn't use an IV). Don't pad. S. [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nVyghX).

Comment: @Topaco: Oh, thank you very much!
That was stupid of me! I misunderstood the b'...' in Python and thought it meant "interpret as binary" ...
Nevertheless, the Python code I got is missing a "binascii.unhexlify()" anyway.